# collect lemma with its words in a dict

Tags: python

I have a text file in the format

```
word lemma
word lemma
word lemma
```

like this

```
workers  work
went     go
going    go
work     work
working  work
```

What I have to do is to collect in dict the lemma with its words, so the output will like this

```
{work: workers, work, working}
{go: went, going}
```

I tried this

```
mydict = {}
for line in myfile.splitlines():
    lemma = line.split()[1]
    word = line.split()[0]
    mydict[lemma] = word
```

But this code gives the following output:

```
{'work': 'working', 'go': 'going'}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: i think you mean to do `line.split()[1]`. also, this will not work completely because you are going to be overwriting the current value for the key with whatever is next, ie the value for `work` will always be replaced by the last value with `work`. you would not to initialize a list as the value then append each matching matching value to that list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right! The problem is that `mydict[lemma] = word` is going to *overwrite* any existing `word`s associated with that `lemma`. In reality each lemma can have more than one word associated with it , so what we really want to do is add the new word to a collection, rather than overwrite the existing value. The natural way to model this is with a dict of *lists* of strings, rather than a dict of strings.

```
mydict = {}
for line in myfile.splitlines():
    word, lemma = line.split()
    if lemma in mydict:
        mydict[lemma].append(word)
    else:
        mydict[lemma] = [word]
```

What does that `if` statement mean? If there is already an entry for a given `lemma` in `mydict`, then we add it to the list. If it's not already there, we initialise the entry with a singleton list.

I've also taken the liberty of using Python's syntax for unpacking sequences. `word, lemma = line.split()` is equivalent to `word = line.split()[0]; lemma = line.split()[1]`.

One of the nice things about Python is that many simple tasks are catered for by the standard library. This sort of use-case is just what the standard library's [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) was designed for. When you index into a `defaultdict` using the subscripting operator (`dict[x]`), if no value is found it is created using the function you supply. Here, we tell the `defaultdict` to initialise a new list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
```

Now the code is simpler because `defaultdict` is taking care of checking `if lemma in mydict` for us. It'll always give us back a (possibly-empty) list to which we can add the word.

```
for line in myfile.splitlines():
    word, lemma = line.split()
    mydict[lemma].append(word)
```

In a comment, you suggested that you didn't want duplicate `word`s in the output. The standard library can help here, too. [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) is a data structure a bit like a list, except that it doesn't remember the order of the elements, and it automatically removes duplicates. (Under the hood, it works like a `dict` with only keys and no values.)

We just need to change the `defaultdict` function from `list` to `set`, and change the `append` method to the version which works on `set`s (which is called `add`.)

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(set)

for line in myfile.splitlines():
    word, lemma = line.split()
    mydict[lemma].add(word)
```

Comment: What about if there are many same words for one lemma, and I want not duplicates in the words?

Comment: @Fawy Good question! Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) instead of a `list`. `set`s automatically remove duplicates. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

as my comment suggests, you need to make a list as your value, not just setting the value for each key. somethign like this should work.

```
mydict = {}
for line in myfile.splitlines():
    lemma = line.split()[1]
    word = line.split()[0]
    if lemma in mydict.keys():
        mydict[lemma].append(word)
    else:
        mydict[lemma] = [word]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I would suggest using a `defaultdict`, initialized with a `list` from the `collections` module. It fits this case since you can easily add new elements and have the `list` ready for adding elements.

Creating a `defaultdict` is easily done by importing it from collections and providing a `list` as the sole argument:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
```

Then, you can iterate for every line in your file and `append()` the `word` according to the value of `lemma` :

```
with open('lemmaaa', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        lemma = line.split()[1]
        word = line.split()[0]
        mydict[lemma].append(word)
```

Using the input you supplied, `print(mydict)` outputs the mapping you're looking for:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'go': ['went', 'going'], 'work': ['workers', 'work', 'working']})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the <s>insane</s> functional approach to this, there is a "single logical line" way to get it done, that doesn't involve creating an empty dictionary and avoids the repeated calls to `append`

```
import itertools
import operator

with open('myfile.txt') as myfile:
    mydict = dict((k, [p[1] for p in grp]) 
         for k, grp in itertools.groupby(
             sorted(list(reversed(ln.split())) for ln in myfile),
             operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

which says
take each line of the file, split it, then [reverse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) it
[sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) those lines
[group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) them by their element[`[0]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
map the element `[0]` to each word in the group by taking the `[1]` of the reversed split line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import collections

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for word, lemma in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        answer[lemma].append(word)
```

If you want to do this without any help from csv:

```
answer = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        word, lemma = line.split()
        if lemma not in answer: answer[lemma] = []
        answer[lemma].append(word)
```